# How to get a camera's frustum information?

Tags: camera, frustum

I have a local coordinate system with three camera normalised directions, `D`, `U` and `R`.

I also have the following information:

```
camera_location
lookat_point
up_direction
distance_near_plane
distance_back_plane
fov
aspect_ratio
```

With this I'm trying to get the information regarding the camera's frustum, the coordinates of it's 8 vertices and the 6 planes that make it up. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to [construct the projection matrix from your info](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html), invert it, and send the 8 device-normalized coordinates of the corners through it. In OpenGL (and I assume Vulkan), those would be:

```
(-1, -1, -1),
(-1, -1, 1),
(-1, 1, -1),
(-1, 1, 1),
(1, -1, -1),
(1, -1, 1),
(1, 1, -1),
(1, 1, 1)
```

In DirectX or Metal, the Z values should be 0 and 1 rather than -1 and 1.